# REST web service invoked from sql server stored procedure through https

Tags: web-services, rest, stored-procedures, https, ssl-certificate

I'm having some problems with invoking my webservice from a stored procedure in sql server 2012.

When I use http protocol the webservice works perfectly, but when I switch to https I get this error in my stored procedure and I just can't figure it out.

> The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect

I would appreciate any kind of help.

I did not use the CLR integration, I am using just a basic stored procedure with sp_OAMethod, sp_OACreate, etc.

If needed I can post my code, but I don't believe that the problem comes from the code (because http works fine).

Thank you in advance for any reply!

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that I can invoke the service with https protocol from any explorer, I get the error only when invoking from my database.

Comment: The SQL Server service will use the system certificate store, while you will use your personal certificate store.  Run `mmc.exe` and add the `Certficates` snap-in from the File menu.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention is that I generated a SSL Certificate from the IIS server and added that with snap-in on the SQL Server's  certificate store in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities. @Andomar Could you please be more specific about the certificates? Which certificate do I need, from which server and where do I put it in database server? Thank you so much, I haven't worked with SSL that much and I have read some articles on the internet, but I didn't fully understand everything.